# chrome webRequest onBeforeRequest event listener not firing until popup has been opened on the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am running a test for an extension I am making. I want the extension to update the badge when any web requests are made, however the badge only begins to update after I have opened the popup. Can someone explain why this is?

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Ad-scan",
"version": "0.1",
"content_scripts": [
{
"js": ["inject.js"],
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
"run_at": "document_start",
"all_frames": true
}
],
"permissions": ["activeTab","declarativeContent","webRequest","webNavigation"],
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
}
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {toInjected: details.url}, function(response){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({webReqUpd: response.totalAds}) //ads are sent to popup
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: response.totalAds.toString()}) //badge is updated  
    })
})},{urls: ["<all_urls>"]});
```

**inject.js**

```
var ads = 0;
var adURLs = [];
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
ads = ads + 1 //ads value is updated
adURLs.push(request.toInjected) //array is updated
console.log(adURLs) //webRequests made on page are logged to console
//logging webRequests array to console to test webRequest event
sendResponse({totalAds: ads})//sending all ads to background
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked that host networks must be specified in the permissions for the webRequest API.
I added permissions for https and http in the manifest, now it works.

```
"permissions": ["activeTab","declarativeContent","webRequest","https://*/*","http://*/*"]
```